# database .txt PHP redirect

Tags: php, database

Good evening I would like to be able to redirect pages in php via my database in txt but I am stuck at this level:

**Database**

### `id|pagea|pageb|pagec;

1|on|on|on|;`

**Redirection.php**

```
$data = file_get_contents("database.txt");
$rows = explode("\n", $data);
$rows = array_map("trim", $rows);
$rowCount = count($rows);

function CountCol($data){
    $col = explode("|", $data);
    return count($col);

}
  

 for ($i=2; $i <$rowCount-1 ; $i++) { 
     for ($j=0; $j < CountCol($rows[$i]) ; $j++) { 
         $column = explode("|", $rows[$i]);

         $id[$i-2]  = $column[0];
         $pagea[$i-2]  = $column[1];
         $pageb[$i-2]  = $column[2];
         $pagec[$i-2]  = $column[3];
    
     }
        
  
 }

$redirectiona = $pagea[1];
$redirectionb  = $pageb[1];
$redirectionc = $pagec[1];

    
    
if($redirectiona = "on"){
        header('location: 1.php');
    }
if($redirectionb = "on"){
        header('location: 2.php');
    
    }
if($redirectionc = "on"){
        header('location: 3.php');
    }
```

It's not working

Comment: Yes there is one line

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the database.txt contains only 1 line of data like the following:

```
1|on|on|on|;
```

Then

- there is no need to explode on "\n". Instead just explode on "|" to assign the exploded data into an array
- you should use == (is equal to) instead of = in your comparison statements (= is an assignment operator : the left operand gets set to the value of the assignment expression on the right)
- as a good practice, put `exit();` after each header location statement

Then the code will be:

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents("database.txt");
$rows = explode("|", $data);

$redirectiona = $rows[1];
$redirectionb = $rows[2];
$redirectionc = $rows[3];
    
if($redirectiona == "on"){
        header('location: 1.php');
        exit();
    }
if($redirectionb == "on"){
        header('location: 2.php');
        exit();    
    }
if($redirectionc == "on"){
        header('location: 3.php');
        exit();
    }
?>
```